# How to add a class to a div on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's what I'm using

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accept").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            $(".generateBtn").addClass("disable");
        } else {
           $(".generateBtn").remove("disable");
        }
    });
});
```

It works after you change the value, but how do I add the style to the div on load to disable?

Do I simpily juse call

```
$(".generateBtn").addClass("disable");
```

Or is there a more elegant technique

Answer (score 0):

How about just triggering a change ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accept").on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            $(".generateBtn").addClass("disable");
        } else {
           $(".generateBtn").remove("disable");
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

I'm guessing you meant to write `removeClass` and not `remove`, if so :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accept").on('change', function () {
        $(".generateBtn").toggleClass('disable', this.value=='0');
    }).trigger('change');
});
```